# Is there a way to remove "try it out" button from instant app on play store

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

We are making an instant app but the client wants to give access to it only specific costumers by sending a link to the. Can we publish and app (that also has instant app) to the play store but disable the instant app from opening through the play store (remove the "try it out" button)?

Comment: You can immediately send the user to "Install" dialog, unless they start from a link. But what will prevent somebody to forward such link to other non-authorized consumers?

Comment: @AlexCohn There would be no consequences only confusion for themselves as it is supposed to open a chat with the support team which they paid for.